# Show element in JavaScript by onkeypress function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to show save button **only if input gets value**,

The issue is if i use `append` for each input i get `1` button printed, what I'm looking for is **regardless of input length get the button only once**.

The important is input not be empty that's all.

## Code

```
<input class="text_dec form-control" type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()" name="text_dec[]" id="'+ textFieldsCount.toString() +'">

function myFunction() {
    $('#moreless').append("button here");
}
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `keypress`, use `keyup`, this will call the listener just when the key is released, so you will have the correct `length` of the input value. With that, you can check if the button must be displayed or not.

Also, I would have another check to make sure that input have some value on it to save when clicked.

Like below, take a look:

```js
$(function(){
    $('.myInput').on('keyup', function(){
        var btnElem = $('.myButton');
        var charLength = this.value.length;
        if (charLength > 0){
          btnElem.show();
        }else {
          btnElem.hide();
        }
    });
    
    $(".myButton").on("click", function(){
      if ($('.myInput').val().trim().length < 1){
        alert("Input is empty")
        return;
      }
      //Do your code
    });
    
});
```

```css
.myButton {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input class="myInput"  type="text" value=""> 
    <input class="myButton" type="button" value="Save Button" />
</body>
```

**EDIT**
Now, if you really need to make as you were doing before (I don't consider it a best practice and also recommend you to rethink if you really wanna go through this) here goes a code that will help you. Click to show.
Here I added the functions and created the button element (if necessary) then append it to DOM just when the input have some value length.

```js
function myFunction(input){
   var btnElem = $(".mySaveButton")[0];
   
   if (!btnElem){
      btnElem = document.createElement("button");
      btnElem.textContent = "Save Button";
      btnElem.onclick = btnClicked;
      btnElem.className = "mySaveButton";
   }

    var charLength = input.value.length;
    if (charLength > 0){
      document.body.append(btnElem);
    }else {
      btnElem.remove();
    }
};

function btnClicked(){
  if ($('.myInput').val().trim().length < 1){
    alert("Input is empty")
    return;
  }
  //Do your code
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <input class="myInput"  type="text" value="" onkeyup="myFunction(this)"> 
</body>
```

Comment: `$(function(){` this part cause problem, as you see i defined `onkeypress="myFunction()"` in my input so i need to say these codes are as `myFunction` function. how should i do that?

Comment: Why this part cause problems? It is the best practice to do with jQuery... it waits for the DOM to be ready, so will confirm that all inputs are loaded before add listeners and functions to it...

Comment: it's not best practice to add javascript listeners inline inside html

Comment: this error is why bro `ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined`

Comment: but you don't need `myFunction()` in this case, the listener is beign added before DOM is ready, no need to add that in the HTML, just remove `onkeypress` from the element in the HTML

Comment: i did that just now, i don't have error but i also don't get the button.

Comment: Did you used the exact code as my snippet above shows? including the html part? if yes, it must work. if it's not working, you have another HTML or JS that is causing some issue

Comment: yes i did the same code as yours just changed input class to mine, still no button and no error

Comment: well i changed your `$(function(){` to mine `function myFunction() {` and now its working perfectly + it does need `onkeypress="myFunction()"`

Comment: Ok, I made an edit showing that approach. I strongly reccomend to not use it, but if this helps, so go on

Answer (score 0):

So I think you just want a button to show to the user once they type something in the text box. If that's the case, then you don't really want to append a button every time they press a key in the box.

Instead I'd make a button and set its css to display none and then when they keydown in the text box change the button's css to display block.

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/wug1bmse/10/

```
<body>
    <input type="text"> 
    <input class="myButton" type="button" value="button text" />
</body>

.myButton {
  display: none;
}

$(function(){
    $('input').on('keypress',function(){
        var htmlElement= $('.myButton');
        htmlElement.css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Comment: that's the one bro, just small change needed, how do i remove back the button once user cleaned the input? `back to display none`

Answer (score 0):

Hiding the element with a class might be easier:

```
.btn-hidden {
    display: none;
}

<input id="save-button" class="btn-hidden" type="button" value="save" />

function showSave() {
    $('#save-button').removeClass('btn-hidden');
}
function hideSave() {
    $('#save-button').addClass('btn-hidden');
}
```

Comment: ? where is the function of your functions? shouldn't `showsave` and `hidesave` be in 1 function and work as keypress?

Comment: The `showSave` must be called from the keypress or whatever you want to use to show the button. Then you can call `hideSave` whenever you want to hide it.